# Pedestrian environment: turtles do not recognise patch-type and surroundings

Tags: netlogo

Recently I've started working on a pedestrian model simulation. I'm currently having a difficult time with controlling the movement patterns of my turtles. My code and blueprint.png is uploaded to Github.

So first, I upload a floor plan and tried `to setup-variables` and `ask patches with pcolor = 0` to set as walls, `pcolor = white` to set as the ground, `pcolor = red` for doors, etc.

I'm able to create turtles, and let's say they start at the doors. I've tried to instruct them to avoid walls, yet the code breaks with runtime error: `MOVE-TO expected input to be an agent but got NOBODY instead`. Why can turtles start at patches with a colour but not a patch-type?

Even just the way the turtles are walking is unlike previous models I've tested in the model library. Any feedback would be welcome and appreciated. Thanks

Netlogo Code

```
extensions [ time ]

globals [
  time-passed
  walls
  doors
  exits
  ground
  art
  corners-top-left
  corners-top-right
  corners-bottom-left
  corners-bottom-right
]

patches-own [
  patch-type
]

turtles-own
[
  speed
  wait-time
]

to setup
  clear-all
  import-dwg
  setup-turtles
  setup-variables
  reset-ticks
end

to go
  move
  tick
  update-time
end

to import-dwg
  import-pcolors "blueprint.png"
end

to update-time
  let minutes floor (ticks / 60)
  let seconds ticks mod 60
  if(minutes < 10)[set minutes (word "0" minutes)]
  if(seconds < 10)[set seconds (word "0" seconds)]

  set time-passed (word minutes ":" seconds)
end

to setup-turtles
  create-turtles 2 [
    move-to one-of patches with [ patch-type = "ground" ]
    set heading towards one-of patches with [ pcolor = 65 ]    
  ]
  ask turtles [
    set speed 1
    set wait-time 0
    set size 2
    set color blue
    pen-down
  ]
end

to move
  ask turtles [
    If any? Patches with [ pcolor = white ]
    [set heading towards one-of patches with [ pcolor = white ]
      fd 1] 
  ]
  tick
end

to setup-variables
  
  ask patches with [ pcolor = 0 ] [
    set patch-type "walls"
  ]
  ask patches with [ pcolor = 15 ] [
    set patch-type "doors"
  ]
  ask patches with [ pcolor = white ] [
    set patch-type "ground"
  ]
  ask patches with [ pcolor = 65 ] [
    set patch-type "art"
  ]
 
  set time-passed "00:00"
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Cross-posted to Reddit and found my answer ([link](https://www.reddit.com/r/NetLogo/comments/mcsb8k/help_turtles_do_not_recognise_patchtype_and/)):

> You're going to hate this - in your setup function, setup-variables needs to be before setup-turtles, otherwise it doesn't know what "patch-type" is.
>
> Edit: Also using "neighbors" for your move so they're looking at
> adjacent patches, may help them not walk through walls and art.